# Flutter: How to save data from elements of ListView?

Tags: flutter, listview

I have a ListView.builder that contains a number of CustomCards:

```
ListView.builder(
   itemCount: list.length,
   itemBuilder: (context, index) {
     return CustomCard(
        data: list[index],
    }
),
```

The CustomCard widgets contain a TextField that can be edited. When the user has changed the data from the CustomCard widgets, the data should be saved by pressing a button. I inserted a screenshot for an easier understanding:

[image]

My problem is now how to access the data from the ListView / CustomCards. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49828488/14434426) Rémi Rousselet wrote that "in Flutter data can only be passed downward". Therfore I can not add the wanted data to a constructor or use a BuildContext. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51494550/14434426) answer from Günter Zöchbauer says that it is expensive to use GlobalKeys for ListViews. Another idea would be to merge the two widgets into one and use a TextEditingController like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59560428/14434426) by João Soares. I think this would in my case lead to really messy code that I try to avoid.

How can I realize saving data from all CustomCards of the ListView at the same time? What is the easiest, least expensive and cleanest way to do it? Is there a concept that I do not know or do not undestand correctly?

Comment: Are you using a Provider?  If so, each element in the list can use it to access a backing Bloc or ViewModel, and call the appropriate 'update' method with the the corresponding data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to have two inputs at each line in the ListView widget, I hope the example below is helpful.

Solution ^^

> create a class in which you declare a list of TextEditingController

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {


 List<CustomCardController> _customCardControllers = [];
 List<CustomCard> _customCards = []
..add(CustomCard("US","UK"))
..add(CustomCard("TUNSIA","JAPON"))
..add(CustomCard("JAPON","CANADA"))
 ;


 @override
void initState() {
   super.initState();

    _customCardControllers = List.generate(_customCards.length, 
(index) => CustomCardControllers(_customCards[index]));
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("test"),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: _customCardControllers.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return 
 
 
_creatCustomCard(_customCardControllers[index].customCard,index);
            }
        ),
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: getAllValues, child: 
 Text("SAVE"))
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
      }

      Widget _creatCustomCard(CustomCard customCard,int index) {
   return Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  key: UniqueKey(),
  children: [
    Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(child: Text("${customCard.arrival}"),flex: 1),
        Expanded(child: Text("
${customCard.departure}"),flex: 1),
      ],
    ),
    Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex:1,
          child: TextField(
            controller: 
 _customCardControllers[index].textEditingControllers![0],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex:1,
          child: TextField(
            controller: 
_customCardControllers[index].textEditingControllers![1],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    SizedBox(height: 15,)
  ],
);
  }

 void getAllValues() {
  for(int i=0;i<_customCards.length;i++){
  String value1 
 =_customCardControllers[i].textEditingControllers![0].text;
  String value2 
 =_customCardControllers[i].textEditingControllers![1].text;
  print("$i :  arrival ${_customCards[i].arrival} : $value1 | 
departure ${_customCards[i].departure} : $value2");
  }
 }
  }

class CustomCardController{
final CustomCard customCard;
  List<TextEditingController> ? textEditingControllers;

 CustomCardController(this.customCard){
  textEditingControllers = []
  ..add(new TextEditingController())
  ..add(new TextEditingController());

 }

 }

 class CustomCard{
  final String arrival;
  final String departure;

 CustomCard(this.arrival, this.departure);
 }
```

[![enter image description here][1]]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0NTr.png

Comment: Does this also work if CustomCard is not a "normal" class but a widget in another file?

Comment: I thought that you posted the image containing dynamic data which maybe are retrieved from the API  like Sport-Union Nickarsulm, SVG Frieberg .... I didn't know what the context of your project was . If I was right what I thought, here you create a model class for dynamic data like a CustomCard class for exemple. But if  data are static , not dynamic, that means there is nothing from the API or something else,  in this case,  you can simply add a list of TextEditingController as a variable into the widget

Comment: You have been completely right. It just took me some time to understand the concept. For further information I recommend this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6PCE3HUnF64&ab_channel=OvidiusMazuru)